# append single quotes to characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string like

```
var test = "1,2,3,4";
```

I need to append single quotes (`' '`) to all characters of this string like this:

```
var NewString = " '1','2','3','4' ";
```

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: It seems you've already answered to your own question  : `test = "'1','2','3','4'";`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I would split the string into an array, which then makes it easier to manipulate into any form you want. Then, you can glue it back together again with whatever glue you want (in this case `','`). The only remaining thing to do is ensure that it starts and ends correctly (in this case with an `'`).

```
var test = "1,2,3,4";

var formatted = "'" + test.split(',').join("','") + "'"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var newString = test.replace(/(\d)/g, "'$1'");
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tmthn/) (please open your JavaScript/developer console to see the output).

For multiple-digits:

```
var newString = test.replace(/(\d+)/g, "'$1'");
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tmthn/1/).

References:

- [Regular expressions (at the Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: +1 great answer : p.s. isnt it suppose to be $0 ? ( there is only 1 group)

Comment: @Billy, yes, by design (since there were only single numbers in the posted question). As Royi suggests, however, that can be easily amended.

Comment: @DavidThomas why $1 and not $0  ?

Comment: I think this is a good answer. I would probably code it like this myself. With my answer, I went for only using string manipulation, as it is less error prone (when the regex becomes more complex), more efficient (only relevant on larger sets of data) and more easily adapted to other circumstances. Personally I love regex, but there is that famous quote... "if you have a problem, and you try to solve it with regex, now you have two problems" ,~)

Comment: @Royi, I could be wrong but I'm pretty certain it's `$1`. As for *why*, I honestly don't know. I can't even verify at the moment as I'm away from a computer and using my phone in between a dozen other things. I'll check tonight though, when I get a minute...if only out of curiosity =)

Comment: @DavidThomas you are not wrong, it should remain `$1`. I tested it with both, and only works correctly with `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

A short and specific solution:

```
"1,2,3,4".replace(/(\d+)/g, "'$1'")
```

A more complete solution which quotes any element and also handles space around the separator:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(/\s*,\s*/).map(function (x) { return "'" + x + "'"; }).join(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler

```
test = test.replace(/\b/g, "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
var NewString = test.replace(/(\d+)/g, "'$1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is actually like an array, so you can do something like this:

```
var test = "1,2,3,4";
var testOut = "";
for(var i; i<test.length; i++){
   testOut += "'" + test[i] + "'";
}
```

That's of course answering your question quite literally by appending to each and every character (including any commas etc.).

If you needed to keep the commas, just use `test.split(',')` beforehand and add it after. 
(Further explanation upon request if that's not clear).